# About the asymptotic normality of the maximum likelihood estimator of the binomial distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, asymptotics, normal-distribution

## Question

r.v. $X \sim B(n, \theta)$.

I want to show that $\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}-\theta)}{\sqrt{\theta(1-\theta)}}$ converges in distribution to the standard normal distribution when $n\to \infty$.

## What I know

From the asymptotic normality of the maximum likelihood estimator, the following holds

\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}(\hat\theta - \theta) \overset{L}{\to} N(0, 1/\mathbb{I}_\theta)
\end{align}

where $\mathbb{I}_\theta$ is the Fisher information.

\begin{align}
\mathbb{I}_\theta = \frac{n}{\theta(1-\theta)}.
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\therefore \sqrt{n}(\hat\theta - \theta)\overset{L}{\to} N(0, \frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{n})\\
\therefore \frac{\sqrt{n}(\hat\theta - \theta)}{\sqrt{\frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{n}}} \overset{L}{\to} N(0,1)\ ???
\end{align}

Comment: Assuming $\hat \theta = \frac Xn$, this looks like the central limit theorem with $n$ iid Bernoulli random variables

Comment: Here Fisher information is used for a single observation, so $I(\theta)=1/(\theta(1-\theta))$. There cannot be $n$ in the limiting distribution after you have taken the limit as $n \to \infty$.